# Symfony 2 lags on ubnutu and making it too slow

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu

I'm working on a symfony 2 project and everything worked so good until today. I have a logged in user, I clicked on a button and suddenly I've got an error that looks like [this](http://somethingemporium.com/2007/06/obscure-error-with-php5-on-debian-ubuntu-session-phpini-garbage) :

ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php5) failed: Permission denied (13) in /your/file/here on line 30.

I said it looks like because I tried to refresh the page unconsciously so it would go away and yes it did go away but then my project doesn't work as it used to be, for example, I have this line on my /index page:

```
{{ render(controller('OCUserBundle:RegistrationApprenant:register',{'request': app.request}))}}
```

that renders the registration template. The index page is stuck at that point and doesn't load the rest of the code, ubuntu becomes too slow the mouse hardly moves. No one touched my code, few minutes ago it was working like a charm.
 I followed a tutorial to set session.gc_probability to 0 (I don’t even know what does the term 'session.gc' mean) , the I tried to see if the index page loads properly but it didn't so I set it back to 1 and came here
Please guys, can someone help me to understand what's happening.

Comment: Reboot the server/computer? Perhaps the web server or php5-fpm needs restarted to make the session.gc_probability take effect?

Answer (score 0):

Clear `Symfony2`'s cache:

```
app/console cache:clear --env=dev
app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make "hard" clean of Symfony2 cache directory.
Delete dev and prod cache directories.

```
rm -rf app/cache/dev  
rm -rf app/cache/prod
```

Answer (score 0):

That does seem like a problem related with the automatic session garbage collection (the `sessions.gc` thing). It depends on how you installed PHP.

You might need to adjust the `session.gc_probability` on your php.ini for Apache (if you're ussing Apache) and then restart Apache.

Please refer to this: http://somethingemporium.com/2007/06/obscure-error-with-php5-on-debian-ubuntu-session-phpini-garbage

If you use nginx / php-fpm you might have to add a line like the following to your pool config:
`php_options 'php_admin_value[session.gc_probability]' => '0'`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This line will delete prod and dev cache folders. This folders will be recreated on creation of the new cache automatically.

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
```